# SharePoint Online : Overwrite a content of file in Document Library using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a document library which is consists of different files. I have a task to Read all the files and overwrite the content in it and Upload back to the SharePoibnt online.

I need to do this as a migration process and must be done in AppUpgraded.

I tried with file.SaveBinary(write.ToArray()) , it pass the code but did not update the file data.

Example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a how I use `FileCreationInformation` to upload local files to SharePoint Online:

```
var list = cc.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
cc.Load(list);
cc.ExecuteQuery();

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
    fileInfo.ContentStream = fs;
    fileInfo.Url = fileName;
    fileInfo.Overwrite = true;

    var newFile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);

    cc.Load(newFile);
    cc.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

You can try creating a `FileCreationInformation` object out of your stream and `File` object. You should be able to achieve the same results. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Groveale but I solved it. That is my mistake as I am not updating the file in the doc lib with execute query. Thaks for the help. I can not upvote becuase I am not sure if this will work or not